# PHP (Laravel) and queued events, at what point is the session no longer accessible?

Tags: php, laravel, session, queue

This question is more ignorance on my part about how sessions work behind the curtains...  But I'm working with Laravel 5, I have a very simple controller statement that sets a session variable when a user visits the site by clicking on a referral link.

```
public function checkReferralCode($code)
{
    session(['referral_code'=>$code]);
    ....
```

this session value is of course available throughout the project with

```
session('referral_code');
```

my question is, what happens if I call an event that is queued and later processed with say Beanstalkd? If that event needs a session variable, will that event lose track of what the session and session variables are?  In other words, should I make sure to pass those variables to the queued event to ensure access?

Right now my events are simply synchronous, but I'd like to make sure if I ever need to implement beanstalkd, that I don't have any surprises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless of whether an event is queued or not your event listener should never reach out to session. An event instance is a simple DTO (data transfer object) and should contain **everything** your event listener needs to process the event.

```
class ReferralCodeChecked extends Event
{
    use SerializesModels;

    public $referralCode; // store a referral code

    public function __construct($referralCode)
    {
        $this->referralCode = $referralCode;
    }
}

class ReferralCodeCheckListener
{
    public function handle(ReferralCodeChecked $event)
    {
        // do whatever you need with referral code
        // $event->referralCode
    }
}

// pass in a referral code when you fire an event
event(new ReferralCodeChecked($code));
```

Comment: Thank you sir, I've heard of DTOs but never have learned much about them, I will certainly do some more reading.

Comment: should I be sending the entire `referralcode` object to the event?  or is it OK for the event to reach out to the database to get the additional information if needed?  (Let's assume i want to check the referral code expiration...)